# Editable Graphics most simplistic method

Tags: print-design, text

I have a high res PDF file that contains a background image and colour all I want to do is change the name and dates ...its a personalised poster.

I do have access to Ai, Photoshop, and In-Design but what program is going to work best to make these changes ..I am new to Ai and InDesign.

Thanks

Comment: Just open it up with Illustrator. As long as the text hasn't been converted the lines you should be ok

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Adobe Acrobat, If fonts are not converted to outlines. Open PDF with Acrobat, go to the Edit->Edit Text & Images.